# using dplyr pipe to remove empty columns in a list of dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a list of dataframes:

**DF**

> LIST <- list(df1 <- data.frame(col_a1 = c("a","b"), col_b2=c(NA,NA)),
>   df2 <- data.frame(col_b2 = c("a","b"), col_b1=c(NA,NA)))
>
> ```
> [[1]]
>   col1 col2
> 1    a   NA
> 2    b   NA
>
> [[2]]
>   col2 col1
> 1    a   NA
> 2    b   NA
> ```

I would like to remove the columns where all entries are NA, and select the ones that contain "1" using pipes

The resulting dataframe list is

```
[[1]]
cola1
a
b
```

I would prefer to use pipes to streamline this. The following code is what I've been trying:

```
LIST %>%
   map(~ .x %>% select(contains("1") & !all(is.na(.))))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use two `select` functions :

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

LIST %>% map(~ .x %>% select(contains("1")) %>% select_if(!all(is.na(.))))


#[[1]]
#  col_a1
#1      a
#2      b

#[[2]]
#data frame with 0 columns and 2 rows
```

Using only one `select` function we can do :

```
LIST %>% map(~ .x %>% select_if(str_detect(names(.x), '1') & 
                               colSums(!is.na(.x)) > 0))
```

---

And similarly in base R :

```
lapply(LIST, function(x) x[colSums(!is.na(x)) > 0 & grepl('1', names(x))])
```